# How do you convert an infintesimal generator of a Markov process to a transition function?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Suppose a continuous-time continuous-step Markov stochastic process $X_t$ has infinitesimal generator $\mu(x, t)$, $\sigma(x, t)$ ($\mu$, $\sigma$, and $X_0$ are known).  How can we use this information to find a density function for the value of $X_t$ (at some fixed time $t$)?

Comment: Integrate the associated differential equation, if possible.